# Issue with code not tentering the if loop in PowerShell

Tags: switch-statement, powershell-5.0

I think this is dumb question but needs attention, cause I got stuck with it for some long time. I have some PowerShell code which needs help. In this code, I pass the input '1' for `switch` condition and 'True' for the next prompt, it is entering the 1st `if` condition, but not entering the 2nd `if` condition, even if I pass `$prd`'s input as foo.

Have tried by declaring the variable `$prd="Global"`, still not working.

```bsh
[String]$prd = Read-Host "Enter the software to update"
[bool]$upg = $true
$param = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the input for upgrade"
switch ($param) {
    0 {
        # Some condition
    }
    1 {
        [String]$sftup = "Going for sftwre updte"
        $sftd_up = Read-Host -Prompt $sftup
        if ($sftd_up -eq $upg) {   # -------->1st if
            Write-Host "foo upgrade"
            if ($prd -eq "foo") {  # ----------> 2nd if
                $nameprd = New-Item -Path "D:\Temp" -ItemType "directory"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FTR, `if` statements are conditionals, not loops.

Comment: What is the output of `"-${prd}-"` inside the outer `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  (The new-item line I put in single quotes.)  The third answer could be any string.

```
Enter the software to update: foo
Enter the input for upgrade: 1
Going for sftwre updte: true
foo upgrade
$nameprd = New-Item -Path "D:\Temp" -ItemType "directory"
```